# How to show integer from activity in XML?

Tags: xml, android, integer

I use XML output in my app. So basically the main activity just tells the android to show the XML layout of main.

But what if I have in the activity code defined integer variable and I want this integer variable also be shown on the display?

How do I PUSH the integer variable to the XML??? From main XML reference to other strings in XML is easy - @string/app_name ... but how do I use the integer variable from the activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you're showing some text in a `TextView`.

You can display text either from a string resource (defined in XML and referred to as `R.string.*`, as you mention) or from a `String` at runtime.

You can't change the XML resources at runtime; you use them for fixed values like labels or other UI text.  So there's no way to "push" a value to XML.

But you can happily do something like this at runtime, dynamically updating your UI:

```
int userAge = calculateUsersAge();
TextView age = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.age_field);
age.setText(userAge +" years old");
```

Or better, ensuring there are no hardcoded values in the code:

```
age.setText(getString(R.string.years_old, userAge));
```

Where `years_old` is the text "%d years old" in your `res/values/strings.xml` and "%d Jahre alt" in your `res/values-de/strings.xml`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
int app_Integer = 10;
```

Convert from int to String to set in your textview::

```
String app_String = "" +app_Integer;
```