# TextView defined in main.xml - how to "name" it to be able to use - setText() method?

Tags: xml, android, textview, settext

I am exploring android and developement and I found one problem.

My app UI is defined in main.xml

I have 2 texts and 2 buttons defined - easy app.

I read that I may be able to change TEXT in the ACTIVITY using the setText() method.

And thats the problem - how do I POINT the setText() Method? How do I tell it to change a specified text?

If I would declare the TextView inside the Activity with NEW TextView NAME Object, I would just need to use NAME.setText(STRING)... But I didnt so i dont have anything like NAME of the object?

How can this be done?

Comment: This is essentially an exact duplicate of the question you asked earlier, except replacing "Integer" with "String".  See my answer on there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2859850/view-problem-how-to-show-integer-from-activity-in-xml/2860062#2860062

Comment: Yeah that one helped but (R.id.name_of_your_textview) is something I cannot figure out so I made a new question out of it ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need do define a new TextView. You need this code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_of_your_textview);
textView.setText("bla bla bla");
```

Comment: yes but what is R.id.name_of_your_textview ??

where do I specify the view name?

you know my XML looks like :

<TextView  
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/how_to"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    />

I dont see any ID or name there :((

Comment: then add a line in your XML:

android:id="@+id/name_of_yout_textview"